# Checking status/event of icon - Selenium, Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

With covid and online schooling, it's hard to keep up with my kid keeping up! I'm only a little familiar with Python and less familiar with webstuff and selenium, but I wanted to try to make it easier to check on whether he's finishing his assignments each day by writing a script that (1) goes to the class webpages, (2) looks for the 'Overdue' text in the outer HTML, and (3) does something (e.g., print 'There is an overdue assignment') if the find method succeeds.

I've completed 1 successfully and know how to do part 3, but can't figure out part 2.

I found what I think is the relevant part on the pages with the inspect element:

```
<i class="icon-minimize" aria-label="This assignment is overdue" title="This assignment is overdue"></i>
```

And I've tried the following code variations:

```
overDue = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("This assignment is overdue")
```

```
overDue = driver.find_element_by_name("This assignment is overdue")
```

And I've tried to copy the CSS Selector and use

```
overDue = driver.find_element_by_class_name("i.icon-minimize:nth-child(1)")
```

I also tried XPath, but I forget now exactly what my code was. Something like:

```
overDue = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[., text()="This assignment is overdue"])
```

But all of these return a NoSuchElement exception. Is there something wrong with my syntax or am I using the wrong methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
overDue = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="This assignment is overdue"]')
```

its title , use @title to validate the value of title attribute

**xpath syntax is**

```
//tagname[@attribute="attributevalue"]
```

so tag_name is i

```
 driver.find_element_by_tag_name("i")
```

there is no name attribute so you cannot use

```
   driver.find_element_by_name
```

class is 'icon-minimize' you should not mention tag there:

```
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon-minimize")
```

Comment: It works! Thanks so much. (Though I had some syntax errors that are reproduced in your fix, my bad.)

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign

Comment: Will do! (Right now I'm on a countdown timer before I can click it. Must be a safety check for new accounts?)